# Error installing gem twitter on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, twitter

Am trying to install twitter gem on Ubuntu 15.04 and this error keeps popping up

```
gem install twitter
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing twitter:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
```

Comment: also relevant for twitter_ebooks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is no ruby development environment installed. Development environment is needed to compile ruby extensions,

You should install development first using command below:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and i solved it by installing ruby-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```